# Unused type parameter on closure argument

Tags: rust

This works:

```
struct Foo<T, F>
where
    F: Fn() -> Option<T>,
{
    f: F,
}
```

but this gives me compile errors:

```
struct Bar<I, T, F>
where
    F: Fn(I) -> Option<T>,
{
    f: F,
}
```

```
error[E0392]: parameter `I` is never used
 --> src/lib.rs:1:12
  |
1 | struct Bar<I, T, F>
  |            ^ unused parameter
  |
  = help: consider removing `I`, referring to it in a field, or using a marker such as `std::marker::PhantomData`

error[E0392]: parameter `T` is never used
 --> src/lib.rs:1:15
  |
1 | struct Bar<I, T, F>
  |               ^ unused parameter
  |
  = help: consider removing `T`, referring to it in a field, or using a marker such as `std::marker::PhantomData`
```

Why is using a type parameter in the closure's return type ok, but not in its arguments?

I can get around it by storing the closure as a trait object:

```
struct Bar<I, T> {
    f: Box<Fn(I) -> Option<T>>,
}
```

but I'd like to avoid this if possible.

Comment: the long answer to this is basically [rfc 738 on variance](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0738-variance.md)

Comment: " Why is using a type parameter in the closure's return type ok, but not in its arguments?" I suspect this is somehow connected with the fact that closure return type is modeled with associated type on the corresponding trait while argument types are type parameters of that trait, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev yes, that is mentioned towards the end of the rfc I linked, in [rules for associated types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0738-variance.md#rules-for-associated-types)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [@VladimirMatveev says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30142155/unused-type-parameter-on-closure-argument#comment48398445_30142155), the return type of a closure is an associated type.

An associated type is different from a type parameter because its value is determined when you *implement* a trait, not when you use it in a call.
In `Fn(I) -> Option<T>`, once you have the input (of type `I`) and the implementation (the particular operations defined in the closure you're passing), the `Option<T>` output is determined.

For `I` it's different, though. You need to either use the type in the struct, or to show the compiler *how it would be theoretically used*, with a `PhantomData` field.

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct Bar<I, T, F>
where
    F: Fn(I) -> Option<T>,
{
    f: F,
    _marker: PhantomData<I>,
}
```

`PhantomData` is only used to check types, but is erased in the generated code, so it does not occupy any memory in your struct (that's why it's a phantom).

The reason why it is needed is explained in detail in [RFC 738 on variance](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0738-variance.md). I'll try to give you a shorter (and hopefully correct) version here.

In Rust, you can most of the times (but not always!) use a longer lifetime where a shorter one is expected.

```
fn foo<'short, 'long>(_a: &'short i32, b: &'long i32)
where
    'long: 'short,
{
    let _shortened: &'short i32 = b; // we're binding b to a shorter lifetime
}

fn foo2<'short, 'long>(_a: &'short i32, b: &'long Cell<&'long i32>)
where
    'long: 'short,
{
    let _shortened: &Cell<&'short i32> = b;
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0887cf999f4a3003de2e8394993328cb&version=beta))

The RFC explains why `Cell` expects exactly the same (and not a longer) lifetime, but for now I suggest you just trust the compiler that it would be unsafe to allow `foo2` to compile.

Now pretend you have a

```
struct Foo<T> { t: T }
```

That `T` can be anything, including a type that holds references.
In particular, `T` can be a type like `& i32` or a type like `&Cell<&i32>`.
As with our `foo` functions above, Rust can infer just fine when it can or can't allow us to assign to a shorter lifetime by inspecting the type of `T` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=166c47c1494e36bffd6b884f6515687f&version=beta)).

However, when you have an unused type parameter, inference does not have any field to inspect to know how it should allow the type to behave with lifetimes.

If you have

```
struct Foo<T>; // unused type parameter!
```

Rust asks you to specify with a `PhantomType` if you wish your `T` to behave as if it was a `& i32` or like a `Cell`. You would write:

```
struct Foo<T> {
    marker: PhantomData<T>, // this is what you usually want
                            // unless you're working with unsafe code and
                            // raw pointers
}
```

or you could write:

```
struct Foo<T> {
    marker: PhantomData<Cell<T>>
}
```

Comment: In the first example I'm thinking you should use `PhantomData<fn(I)>`. I'd do that to make sure it was right.

Comment: @bluss ok, this is hurting my head a little, but I think you already have a concrete `f: F`, so you don't need a `PhantomData` to tell `I` to behave like the argument to a closure. What you're trying to constrain is I itself. I'm not sure if at this point you should make a decision on the closures you want to use with `Bar`. (i.e. Do I need `PhantomType<Cell<&i32>>` if I'm planning to use closures like `Fn(Cell<&i32>)` or it makes no difference in this case?)

Comment: My head hurts as well, to be sure, but I think `fn(I)` and plain `I` have opposite variance w.r.t to `I`. What I meant was that even if they are the same, I know `fn(I)` will be right, because that's how the type behaves -- like a function that needs `I`. :-)

Comment: I think the breakdown is basically this. Depending on the type variable `X`, we have covariant: `X` and `fn() -> X`, contravariant: `fn(X)`, invariant: `Cell<X>`.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to using dynamic dispatch via the trait object is to use [`std::marker::PhantomData`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html) for this:

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct Bar<I, T, F>
where
    F: Fn(I) -> Option<T>,
{
    f: F,
    _i: PhantomData<I>,
    _t: PhantomData<T>,
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f8ad185eb8abaaa7e945d4c76a3b1cc9))

You "instantiate" a `PhantomData` just by using `PhantomData`, e.g.

```
let phantom: PhantomData<T> = PhantomData;
```

Comment: Could you explain more why `PhantomData` is needed in this case? The docs say *"a type acts as if it stores a value of type T, even though it does not"*, but the struct `Bar` shouldn't be storing anything of type `I` or `F` it seems.

Comment: I honestly have no idea. I figured it was a limitation of the type system. Also, looking at the 'ownership' section, it's probably preferable to have it as `PhantomData<*const T>`, though I'm not sure.

Comment: you don't need `_t`, just `_i` is enough (and the question is asking why that is the case)

Comment: A PhantomData in this case will make `I` and `T` used by the struct effectively removing the unused type parameters error without adding any overhead to the struct size.