# Is it possible to have a closure in a structure with generic arguments and return type?

Tags: generics, rust, closures

Is it possible to replace the closure below with generic arguments and return type?

```
struct HMHolder<T>
where
    T: Fn(u32) -> u32,
{
    calculation: T,
    value: HashMap<String, i32>,
}
```

For example, can I make the `Fn<U, V>(x: U) -> V` in that struct and create a constructor?

Comment: What happens when you replace the concrete types with more generics?

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Unused type parameter on closure argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30142155/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: @Shepmaster, Thanks. Was looking for this. Was not sure about the syntaxes. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe like this (specifying a phantom type for the otherwised unused type parameters):

```
struct HMHolder<I, R, Calculation>
where
    Calculation: Fn(I) -> R,
{
    calculation: Calculation,
    value: std::collections::HashMap<String, i32>,
    marker: std::marker::PhantomData<(I, R)>,
}
```

Comment: How to call it from another function like: fn calculate_value(&mut self, arg: u32) -> HashMap<T,R> {    
        
        for i in 0..arg {
            let v = (self.calculation)(i);
            
            self.value.insert(i, v);            
        }
        
        self.value
    }    , which gives the error "mismatched types" in (self.calculation)(i). Thanks.